# I'm getting error when creating project Prism Unity App (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

When I'm creating project Prism Unity App (Xamarin.Forms) I have an error "Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Templates.VisualStudio'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates."

I didn't get this error when I used Prism Unity App (WPF) or Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared) templates.

How can I fix this problem? Please help

Comment: Please add more information about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarin.Forms templates requires the latest version of Xamarin to be installed.  Update your Xamarin install.